# Find a file with Quick Open within a particular (multi-root workspace) root in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I limit my Quick Open results to a particular (multi-root workspace) root directory?

---

VS Code has a handy Quick Open (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) feature. Using it, I can enter partial paths and match a file. For example, if I want to open the file located at `src/v1/js/shared/foo.js` I can enter `v1/foo` and find the correct file (as opposed to, say, the foo file located in the `v2` directory).

I have a multi-root workspace, and there are many files with the same name located in my different roots. If I'm performing a global search, I can use `./project1/` to narrow search results to the `project1` root directory.

However, I've found no similar feature when searching for a file using the Quick Open feature. I've tried `./project1/v1/foo`, but Quick Open doesn't find anything.

The [multi-root documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_general-ui) briefly mentions that setting the label format to "medium" will cause Quick Open to include the folder name, but it says nothing about how to limit my search results to a particular root.

Is this possible? Supporting documentation would be appreciated... as I said, I've not found anything that mentions it.

Answer (score 0):

Just include at the beginning of the search input some unique part of the directory name of the root you want to search under and add a directory separator ("/") between that and the rest of what you want to search for ([Quick open does fuzzy search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75964045/11107541)). This even works if the path of one of the roots is the directory containing the .code-workspace file. This feature was added in VS Code 1.44 (see issue ticket [Can't search root folder names in quickopen #32444](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32444))

Note that this feature has been affected by bugs in the past, so if it's not working, it might just be a bug. Ex. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127958.