# VS Code Ctrl+P does not search for filenames correctly,

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to be able to look for a file using Ctrl+P. E.g. I type "ABC" and it will show all files with "ABC" in the filename. (ABCXXX.js, XABCXX.js, ...)

But now, it will search all file with the alphabet A, B and C inside (eg "b**ab**el.**c**onfig.json")

I checked the bindings and it says Ctrl+P = "Go to file".

How can I reset this behaviour to the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that's how it's always worked (or at least- that's how it's worked for several versions now). That behaviour is called "fuzzy matching", and that input box is called "Quick Open".

You may be interested in the following feature-request issue ticket: [Add a setting to disable fuzzy matching in quick open #99171](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99171), which was closed for not receiving enough community support fast enough, but is fortunately still tracked in the larger [Improve ranking of elements in quick open #27317](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27317), which is still open. You can subscribe to those issue tickets to get notified about updates and discussion in them.

For your reference / learning purposes, the above issue ticket was found by googling "`github vscode issues quick open fuzzy matching`".

Comment: oh... I didn't realise that it had always been fuzzy.  May be last time, I had a few files and it matched easily.  Thanks.